# Report on User that added Contact to Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, subscriber-key

I'd like to get a report/data extension/export of which Marketing Cloud user added a Contact.

I can see this on the All Subscribers interface in Email Studio ("Added By" column), but when I export the All Subscriber's table, this is not a column I can select.  I have looked at the Data View for _Subscribers, but this doesn't seem to be a property on that either.

We have several thousand Contacts that were added a few months ago with the incorrect SubscriberKey, but we don't know which user added them. Appreciate any responses or suggestions how to get this information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOTB functionality but once we did a similar check on the project and that is how we proceeded -

1. Get the value from the `AddedBy` field from the [`ListSubscriber`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_listsubscribers.htm&type=0) Data View, which would give you the `AccountUserID` number of the user who added a particular subscriber.

```
SELECT
    AddedBy,
    AddMethod,
    CreatedDate,
    DateUnsubscribed,
    EmailAddress,
    ListID,
    ListName,
    ListType,
    Status,
    SubscriberID,
    SubscriberKey,
    SubscriberType
FROM ent._ListSubscribers
/* adjust timeframe or generally filtering criteria yourself */
WHERE CreatedDate> DATEADD(D, -61, GETDATE()) AND CreatedDate < DATEADD(D, +1, GETDATE())
```

2. Do a retrieve SOAP API call on the [AccountUser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/accountuser.htm) object with a simple filter that would tell you who is this user by its `AccountUserID` number.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:par="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <fueloauth xmlms="http://exacttarget.com">{{AuthToken}}</fueloauth>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>AccountUser</ObjectType>
            <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
            <Properties>Email</Properties>
            <Properties>UserID</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                <Property>AccountUserID</Property>
                <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                <Value>xxxxxxx</Value>
            </Filter>
        </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

3. You can choose whatever needed fields for user identification but it should be sufficient enough to have `Email` and `UserID` (=Username) fields to find the user in the Setup --> Users page